# Web Service incoming data traffic from HTTP(9090) or HTTPS(443)

Tags: java, web-services

I have java web services that are consuming by many external clients. web service is available on both HTTP(9090) and HTTPS(443).

My question is that, Can we identify whether the traffic is coming from HTTP(9090) or HTTPS(443) through java code?

Comment: Can we? Yes, through some means. Should we? No, that sounds like a terrible idea. Why are you even allowing unencrypted connections in the year 2022?

Comment: `request.getServerPort()` can be used

Comment: We need to identify the clients and tell them (selected clients) to upgrade to HTTPS. @Kayaman